# Showing dynamic items list using two tables in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two tables one having advert info which includes id for images table associated with the advert. I am showing the advert information in one single page, how do I send both arrays to the view page. If I write the select for both tables, I get multiple lines since I have multiple images for an advert.

My model functions

```
    public function get_adverts()
    {
        //$this->db->select();
        //$this->db->from('adverts');
        $db_query='select adverts.id,adverts.address,adverts.title,adverts.item_condition, adverts.add_type, adverts.price, adverts.negotiable, adverts.product_description, countries.country_name,states.state_name, cities.city_name, product_pictures.picture_file_name
FROM adverts,countries,cities,states, product_pictures
WHERE adverts.country_id=countries.id and adverts.city_id=states.id and adverts.area=cities.id and adverts.id= product_pictures.add_id';

        $query = $this->db->query($db_query);
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function get_pictures()
    {
        //$this->db->select();
        //$this->db->from('adverts');
        $db_query='select product_pictures.picture_file_name
FROM adverts,product_pictures
WHERE adverts.id=product_pictures.add_id';

        $query = $this->db->query($db_query);
        return $query->result();
    }
```

and my control

```
public function get_products()
{
    // gets all dvertes in the system
    $this->load->model('Product_model');
    $data['products']=$this->Product_model->get_adverts();   // get database query output to the array
    $data['images']=$this->Product_model->get_pictures();
    $array_info2 = array(
        "title" => "Not Found"
    );
    $this->load->view('include/header', $array_info2);
    $this->load->view('include/navbar_logged_in');
    $this->load->view('Site/view_adverts',$data);
    $this->load->view('include/footer');
}
```

This lists all images under one advert, my view portion given below:

```
<div class="container">
<?php foreach($products as $product):?>

    <div class="ad-listing-list mt-20">
        <div class="row p-lg-3 p-sm-5 p-4">
            <div class="col-lg-4 align-self-center">
                <?php foreach($images as $image):?>


                    <img class="image img-thumbnail"  src="<?php echo base_url('/uploads/advert_images/thumbs/'.$image->picture_file_name);?>" >

                <?php endforeach;?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-10">
                        <div class="ad-listing-content">
                            <div>
                                <a href="single.html" class="font-weight-bold"><?php echo $product->id." ".$product->title;?></a>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="list-inline mt-2 mb-3">
                                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="category.html"> <i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i> Electronics</a></li>
                                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href=""><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>26th December</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <p class="pr-5"><?php echo $product->product_description;?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
</div>
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: since i get multiple records, all images come in one record set. function get_pictures() returns all the images for the adverts, i need specific images for a one advert id in one div (the container)

Comment: why not add the pictures with a join in your get_adverts() function. Here is a good read about joins: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, since the div is inside a foreach loop, if there are two or more images for an advert, i get three containers repeated. Anyway to only get addvert specif images inside the container?

Comment: I got it sorted by using an inline sql DB query. Thanks